# How to find the sum of every row above in a grouped data?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a `df`

```
 AccountID       PurchaseDate                 Price
    | 113        2018-09-01 22:56:30              13|
    | 114        2018-09-03 22:57:30              23|
    | 113        2018-09-02 22:56:30              19|
    | 114        2018-09-01 22:56:30              20|
    | 114        2018-09-03 22:56:30              25|
```

I have my `AccountID` already in `groupby()`
How do I create a new column `TotalPurchase` that contains the sum of `Price` but only for the same `AccountID` and `PurchaseDate` before the day for that row?

```
AccountID       PurchaseDate                 Price          TotalPurchase
| 113        2018-09-01 22:56:30              13               0  |
| 113        2018-09-02 22:56:30              19               13 |
| 114        2018-09-01 22:56:30              20               0  |
| 114        2018-09-03 22:56:30              25               20 |
| 114        2018-09-03 22:57:30              23               45 |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following using `shift()` and `cumsum()`:

```
df = df.sort_values(by=['AccountID', 'PurchaseDate'])
df['TotalPurchase'] = df.groupby('AccountID')['Price'].transform(lambda x: x.shift().cumsum()).fillna(0)
```

OUTPUT:

```
  AccountID PurchaseDate        Price   TotalPurchase
0   113     2018-09-01 22:56:30 13     0.0
2   113     2018-09-02 22:56:30 19     13.0
3   114     2018-09-01 22:56:30 20     0.0
4   114     2018-09-03 22:56:30 25     20.0
1   114     2018-09-03 22:57:30 23     45.0
```